# Intersection of the closed unit ball, $\overline{B}$ in C[0,1] with the subspace <t>

Tags: functional-analysis

Here we equip C[0,1] with the supremum norm
That is $f\in C[0,1]$ and $\left \| f  \right \|_{\infty}= \sup \left | f(x ) \right |$

and according to the definitions we have come across:
$\overline{B} =$ {$f\in C[0,1]\mid  \left \| f \right \|_{\infty } \leq 1$}

< t > can be considered as the set of all combinations of t.
ie. {$rt \mid r\in \mathbb{R}$} (here I have considered C[0,1] to be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ ).
 so is there a more simplified way of writing the intersection with < t > and C[0,1]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find all functions of the form $f(t)=rt$, $r\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\sup_{t\in [0,1]} |f(t)|\leq 1$$
You can explicitly compute this sup when $f$ is so simple.

Comment: Thanks. So that means the intersection will result in the set 
{$rt \mid \left | r \right |\leq 1$}

Comment: This is absolutely correct.